# Add rows count in SQL view

Tags: sql, database, view

I'm trying to create a table using SQL view. It suppose to add a column to each row in questions table that will have an integer value of answers given to that question. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Question]
AS
    SELECT 
       COUNT(answer.Id) as 'Answers',
       question.Id,
       question.CreatorId,
       question.Title,
       question.Content,
       question.CreationDate
    FROM 
       Questions AS question 
    JOIN 
       Answers AS answer ON answer.QuestionId = question.Id;
```

I understand that this is not right but I can't think of nothing else. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite, correlated sub-query to get count:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Question]
AS
SELECT (select COUNT(*) from Answers
        where QuestionId = question.Id) as 'Answers',
       question.Id,
       question.CreatorId,
       question.Title,
       question.Content,
       question.CreationDate
FROM Questions AS question;
```

Or, a join with a group by;

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Question]
AS
SELECT COUNT(answer.Id) as 'Answers',
       question.Id,
       question.CreatorId,
       question.Title,
       question.Content,
       question.CreationDate
FROM Questions AS question 
JOIN Answers AS answer
ON  answer.QuestionId = question.Id
GROUP BY question.Id,
         question.CreatorId,
         question.Title,
         question.Content,
         question.CreationDate;
```

Note that columns in select list are either argument to aggregate functions, or also listed in GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

This not creating a table,you are joining

```
var commandStr= "If not exists (select name from sysobjects where name = 'Customer') CREATE TABLE Customer(First_Name char(50),Last_Name char(50),Address char(50),City char(50),Country char(25),Birth_Date datetime)";
```

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStr, con))
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

you need like this

Comment: Wrong tab/window when pasting answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to COUNT all entries you can use this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Question] AS
SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM Questions
```

If you need more complex COUNTing (or other aggregate functions) have a look at that page:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: From the code I have added to the question you can see that I read and understood this part and I know how the COUNT works, The site you proposed is great but there are no answer to my question there.